# go back to the previous mat tab with browser back button

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-tab

I'm developing an angular application , I need to set up the mat tab in such a way that without using the router url, when I click on the browser back button  , it needs to close the tab (mat tab) that is currently open and go back to the previous mat tab that was accessed. how to do that ?

I tried with angular location(history) but it just works only with router URL

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is by storing every tab click in an array:

```
let tabHistory:number[] = [];

tabChanged(tabChangeEvent: MatTabChangeEvent): void {
   tabHistory.push(tabChangeEvent.index);
}
```

Then you have to keep the browser's back button from navigating to the previous page:

```
// the non-angular way
history.pushState(null, '', location.href);

// the angular way ...not sure if this is supported by every browser
import { Location } from `@angular/common`;

constructor(private location: Location) {}

ngOnInit() {
this.location.replaceState('/');
}

/* 
These codes clear the back button history state. It tells the back button the previous url is '' or '/'.
When restoring the back button you can replace it with another url
*/
```

Then on each time you click the back button in the browser read the tab history instead of navigating to a previous page:

```
window.onpopstate = () => {

     // this will return and remove the last tabindex from the array. 
     // this will make your tab switch to the selected tab.
    this.tabIndex = tabHistory.pop();

// When the array is empty you can restore the previous url and restore the back button to the original state.

    
   /*
    Insert back button restore code here.

    Something like:
    if (tabHistory.length === 0) {
        navigate to code
    }
   */
}
```

Your HTML

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="tabChanged($event)" [selectedIndex]="tabIndex">
    <mat-tab></mat-tab>
<mat-tab-group>
```